Parameter 6 of constructor in com.example.moneymanagerbackend.model.Expense required a bean of type 'org.bson.types.ObjectId' that could not be found
package com.example.moneymanagerbackend.model

import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.time.LocalDate

@Component
@Document
data class Expense(
    @Id
    val id: ObjectId = ObjectId(),
    var amount: Double = 0.0,
    var date: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(),
    var recurrence: String = "",
    var description: String = "",
    var category: Category,
    val userID: ObjectId
)

Im a beginner in server-side development. Im using Springboot with kotlin and mongoDB Atlas as the database. Im getting this error and the problem is in the expense model class.

Remove @Component. It doesn't make sense for an @Document to be a spring managed component.

When are you getting the error? At least provide a Stack Trace

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Actually the first comment of M. Deinum is the actual answer. Spring tries to autowire your document because you added @Component. The last two have no default parameter, you spring tries to do constructor injection, finding beans of type ObjectId and Category.
Remove @Document and you should be good.
WRT to your document, I would recommend using @MongoId instead of @Id.
